# Does spriter animation exported as json work on Pixijs?

Tags: animation, pixi.js, spine

I was watching some videos on getting started with Pixijs and in some video they said Spriter can be used for the spine animation. But the exported json doesnt seem to work with pixijs. Anybody has experience using the Spriter exported json in pixijs?